# Does the propagator rule, used in Feyman's famous formula derivation, have an alternative integral definition over all space?

Tags: integration

I've see the following around:

$$ {1\over{A+i\epsilon}} = \int^\infty_0 dt\exp\left(it(A+i\epsilon)\right)$$

It's used in use in "Feyman's famous formula" derivation. Is there an alternative integral definition, for ${1\over{A+i\epsilon}}$, over the full space ($-\infty,+\infty$)? I cannot see where this formula comes from.

Comment: Elaborate on your last sentence. Do you mean you don't understand the given equality, or you don't understand how you would make up a counterpart to this one involving integration over the whole line?

Comment: In the contexts I have seen, integration from 0 to infinity is done as to be able to specify initial conditions. Perhaps there is something similar motivating this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not due to Feynman, but it's called "Schwinger trick", or at least this is what they told us. Feynman parametrisation is indeed something very different.

This is not a question of "where does it come from". It's simply a definition.

Take the function

$$\frac{1}{A}$$

where in this simple case $A$ is just a number. 
Well, this is nothing but the result of a well known integration:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x/A}\ \text{d}x$$

Try to compute it and you'll get the result.

When $A$ is not a number but it's a function (maybe a function of a variable $q$, different from the variable you're integrating to), then the result hold the same. Suppose $A = A(q)$ that can be a polynomial, a trigonometric function or whatever.

The same result holds:

$$\frac{1}{A(q)} = \int_0^{+\infty}\ e^{-x/A(q)}\ \text{d}x$$

Now let's come to your formula. I really suspect it's wrong, because the correct result of that integration shall be

$$\frac{1}{\epsilon - iA} = \frac{i}{A + i\epsilon}$$

In any case, that is nothing but an application of what we just said. More generally:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{i x A}\ \text{d}x = \frac{i}{A} = -\frac{1}{Ai}$$

As long as $\Im\ ( A ) > 0$

In your case it's just

$$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{it (A + i\epsilon)}\ \text{d}t = \frac{i}{A + i\epsilon}$$

Provided that

$$\Re\ (\epsilon) + \Im\ (A) > 0$$

If you extend the range of integration to the whole Real axis, the integral does not converge.

It's just another way to see that writing, and it comes handy in many calculations in quantum field theory for example.